# Restlet Concurrency Issue

Tags: java, restlet

My Restlet seems to become unresponsive after some (very simple) concurrent calls. To reproduce in the easiest way possible, i've set up a simple Application:

```
public final class TestRestlet extends Application {

    public static final String COUNT_10_ROUTE = "/countTen";
    public static final String COUNT_20_ROUTE = "/countTwenty";

    @Override
    public final Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        final Router mainRouter = new Router(getContext());

        mainRouter.attach(COUNT_10_ROUTE, CountToTenResource.class);
        mainRouter.attach(COUNT_20_ROUTE, CountToTwentyResource.class);

        return mainRouter;
    }
}
```

Those resources perform only a simple iteration, as follows:

```
public final class CountToTenResource extends ServerResource {

    @Get
    public Representation count() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("CT10 resource - counted up to " + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return new StringRepresentation("Counted to 10\n");
    }
}
```

... and similarly for the CountToTwentyResource. I start up my restlet like this:

```
final Component component = new Component();
component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 12345);
final TestRestlet testRestlet = new TestRestlet();
component.getDefaultHost().attach(testRestlet);    
component.start();
```

and then I proceed to curl both resources at the same time

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:12345/countTen
curl -X GET http://localhost:12345/countTwenty
```

The first resource successfully returns its message, but the second one seems to freeze and the whole restlet becomes unresponsive from then onwards. I have performed the same test with [this java RESTClient](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/%20%22this%20simple%20java%20RESTClient%203.1) and again the restlet got stuck.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix it? What am I doing wrong? I am using Restlet version 2.1.0.

Comment: should you be catching general exception?  maybe the second call is throwing exception and the server aborts?

Answer (score 0):

Theo, please try adding the Jetty or Simple extension JAR and their dependencies to the classpath. That will replace the internal/default HTTP connector which isn't stable enough.